# Stack Overflow Podcast on SoundCloud

Tags: discussion, podcast, soundcloud

If I am not mistaken, Stack Overflow's official SoundCloud is https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/

But I can see only four new podcasts here (from the last 30 days) - https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/tracks.

Besides these four, there are three more podcasts was published, I found them on the blog, but I couldn't find it on SoundCloud. Can anyone direct me how can I listen to them from SoundCloud, not from embedded on blog?

Comment: do you only see 4 items on the page total? I can see a lot more than that. If that's your problem, maybe try a private browsing window or disable any extensions which might be changing the page for you? Also, I'm on desktop, maybe mobile has a different site version that only shows the most recent items?

Comment: I mean the latest published. I see a lot of them too, but only 4 from last 1 month

Comment: 1. A Few Of Our Favorite Things About React 
2. A Brief History of Black Software
3. TFW You Accidentally Delete Your Database
I couldn't find these 3 podcast on soundclud.

Comment: Workaround: from [the *"Podcast"* link](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast) at the top right of [every podcast announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/03/podcast-black-software-charlton-mcilwain/?cb=1), open [the RSS feed](https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3) in some text form (works directly in Firefox because they have (sadly) removed the RSS reader), and fish out [the (direct download) MP3 link](https://cdn.simplecast.com/audio/6fa1d3/6fa1d34c-502b-4abf-bd82-483804006e0b/cbdb6884-ea6f-48df-8536-cb67ddff39d8/stackoverflow-episode8v2_tc.mp3).

Comment: Ohh , I can listen to them to google podcast too, actually, I'm looking for Soundcloud solution. I'm too much use to on soundcloud.